# JavaScript increment and decrement each time a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, dom, increment

I am trying to increment `upBtn` and decrement `downBtn` by 10,000 each time the button is pushed.  The `downBtn` is decrementing but the `upBtn` is concatenating.  Can someone explain why one is working and why the other is not as well as how I could fix it?  I'm new to coding and could use the help understanding this.

````
    upBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        rocketImg.style.top -= 10;
        document.getElementById('spaceShuttleHeight').textContent += 10000;
    });
    downBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        rocketImg.style.top += 10;
        document.getElementById('spaceShuttleHeight').textContent -= 10000;
    });```
````

Comment: text += results as strings operation, and text -= results as numbers operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt` or similar to let JavaScript know that this should be treated as a number and not a string:

```js
const adjustValue = event => {
  const increasePressed = event.target.id === 'increase';
  const decreasedPressed = event.target.id === 'decrease';

  if (increasePressed || decreasedPressed) {
    const currentValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('#el').innerHTML);
    const el = document.querySelector('#el');

    el.innerHTML = increasePressed ? currentValue + 10000 : currentValue - 10000;
  }
};

document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', adjustValue);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>Current value:&nbsp;</span><span id="el">0</span><br/>
  <input id="increase" type="button" value="Increase" />
  <input id="decrease" type="button" value="Decrease" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

style.top wants px amount. You need to first get the current amount then add/subtract 10 from that and then set it back to the new value.

Comment: Whilst correct, this would be much better with some examples

Answer (score -1):

Your rocketImg.style.top is of type string instead of a number. Try wrapping it in `parseInt()` (or `parseFloat()`, depending on the type), like so: `parseInt(rocketImg.style.top) += 10)`. Javascript automatically performs the conversion for the `-` operator since you can't subtract strings.

Comment: `style.top` expects a numeric value and unit, eg `px`. This won't work unfortunately

Comment: Can't you add the `px` after performing the calculation (and reverting it to a string)? Didn't know that, interesting.